# Playing videos in facebook application

Tags: php, facebook

How do I play videos in facebook fbml application? Is there a tag for that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a [fb:flv tag](http://wiki.developers.facebook.com/index.php/Fb:flv) for just this.  As an aside, they have a handy list of tags available: [All fb tags](http://wiki.developers.facebook.com/index.php/Category:FBML_tags)